# List values from database with foreignkey in grails

Tags: mysql, grails, spring-security

I'm using grails 3.1.10, spring security service and mysql. I have tables: Shop and Product. So shop has many products in my tables. product_id is fk in Shop table. listed all shop at show/index page. when clicked shop name it direct you shop/show/id which shows shop's properties. (I made this sending shop id to url) What I'm trying to do is show all product which belong to this shop. 
I write this method in my shopController

```
def list = {
params.max = Math.min(params.max? params.int('max') : 20, 100)
Product product = Product.get(params.id) 
List districts = Shop.findAllByProduct(product)
[productList : districts,
 producttInstanceTotal: Product.count()]}
```

and in my shop/show.gsp is

```
<g:each in="${productList}" status="i" var="p" >
 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
      <img class="img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
      </a>
        <div class='text-center'>
         <p><g:link controller="product" action="show"  params="[id:p.id]">
                ${fieldValue(bean: p, field: "productName")}
            </g:link></p>
          <p>${fieldValue(bean: p, field: "productName")}</p>
          <p>${fieldValue(bean: p, field: "productBarcode")}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</g:each>
```

but nothing show. By the way I create all controllers and views using generate-all. thanks for any help

Comment: you have def list = { which you should change to def list() { it doesn't render anything instead it outputs the params back onto what it expects to be list.gsp to exist for the controller name. You then refer to myshop/show.gsp - the show.gsp will be bound to def show() { } instead of def list - look for content of list.gsp for debugging - also in you controller add println "-- product is $product" println "districts is $districts" under each of the elements to see if you are even hitting it

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm trying to do is show all product which belong to this shop.

In that case you should pass the shop ID as a parameter to and list all products that belong to it. The code that you've posted above is passing the product ID and listing all shops that sell it.

```
def list() {
  Shop shop = Shop.get(params.id) 
  List products = Product.findAllByShop(shop)
  [productList : products]      
}
```

Notice that the action should be declared as a method `def list() {}` rather than a closure `def list = {}`